# Laravel 4 model with attributes from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, orm, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to have a model that belongs to another one.  In my controller, I'd like to get all items in that model, but I want the attributes from the table it belongs to as well.  For example:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

}
```

In my controller I can do the following to get the comment data:

```
$comments = Comment::first();
```

However, that will only give me data from the comments table (and no joined data from the posts table).  I would like the data from the posts table for the row that each comment belongs to available as attributes to my Comment model.  I know that I can also do the following to get the data from the posts table:

$comments = Comment::first();

The issue with doing it this way is that it uses two database queries (#1 to get the comment, and #2 to get the post data that it belongs to).  Is there a way that I get the data from both tables into my model, equivalent to a join statement:

```
SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN posts ON comments.post_id = posts.id
```

I Know that I build a join query manually without using my Comment or Post models, but I have several methods in my Comment model that I'd like to be able to use with the data that is retrieved.  Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You must first Retrieve the Post and then Retrieve your Comment based on your Post

Like this

$comments = $post->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation on eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

> Thankfully, we can use eager loading to drastically reduce the number of queries. The relationships that should be eager loaded may be specified via the with method [...]

Using the `with()` parameter will use a **constant number**† of queries in a one-to-many relationship. Therefore, this is query should retrieve your comments with their related post in one query:

```
$comments = Comments::with('post')->get();
```

† A Constant number of queries as opposed to linearly increasing in query count per number of comments

Comment: If I add an event listener for the queries, it does show that there are two separate queries still running to get the data:

select * from `comments`
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`id` in (?, ?)

However, if I am retrieving MANY comments, it is still only using 2 total queries instead of 2 queries for EVERY comment.  I think that should be good enough for me.

Comment: Good to know! It appears it's not "one" but rather "few" (constant) queries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the results only with one query done on the background, without using `with()`, you can use `fluent` and `join()`.

```
SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN posts ON comments.post_id = posts.id
```

is equal to:

```
DB::table('comments')
    ->join('posts','comments.post_id','=','posts.id','left')
    ->get();
```

But I think also adding a `groupBy()` statement will give you better results:

Example:

```
DB::table('comments')
    ->join('posts','comments.post_id','=','posts.id','left')
    ->groupBy('comments.id')
    ->get();
```

But I'd prefer to use the other answer in my projects:

```
Comment::with('post')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

$comments:: all()->with ('post')->get()

Comment: `::all()` is not required if you're getting the collection like that. `$comments::with('post')->get()` is the correct usage

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this method also uses two database queries to retrieve the information (#1 for comment data and #2 for post data).  Isn't there a way to retrieve it all using a single query?

Comment: @matt You will need to use `fluent` and `join()` then. But @kaning 's approach is more _laravelish_.

Comment: Using `with()` **DOES** use one query. Not using `with()` and calling `$comment->post` later in execution triggers a 2nd query. See the [docs on eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) for more information.